prove that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty }\sqrt[3]{3n}{x_{n}}=1$
the problem :
let ${x_{n}} \in \mathbb{R}$  with $ \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty }{x_{n}}\sum_{1}^{n}x_{k}^{2}=1$ prove that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty }\sqrt[3]{3n}{x_{n}}=1$
let say i am stuck all i came up with since the series ${x_{n}}\sum_{1}^{n}x_{k}^{2}$ converges then $x_{n}$ converges to 0
I couldnt understand the solution which you can find in this paper in the last page  :
https://www.ssmrmh.ro/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/SOME-TECHNIQUES-OF-USING-THE-STOLZ-CESAROS-THEOREM.pdf

Asked and answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/991753/42969, and here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/204896/42969
